# libxml2 - get node(xmlNodePtr) content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, libxml2

I parsed and have pointer `xmlNodePtr` upto category tag, But I want to get the value of the node(name) like `TrailersFreeMovies , Trailers` in an array.

```
<categories><category><name>TrailersFreeMovies</name><url>https://www.ex1.com/srs/index.php?cid=47</url></category><category><name>Trailers</name><url>https://www.ex1.com/srs/index.php?cid=45</url></category></categories>
```

guide me to parse this

Comment: libxml2 can be confusing to a newcomer. I would honestly recommend using a simpler library if performance isn't of the essence.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the libxml2 examples, specifically `tree1.c`, which shows how to navigate a document and get contents.
http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#tree1.c

Answer (score 0):

[XPath](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html) part of the api returns an array of nodes. See [XPath examples](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#XPath).

Once you obtain the result of [xmlXPathEvalExpression](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathEvalExpression) as `xpathObj` then the array is in `xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab`. `nodesetval` is a pointer to [xmlNodeSet type](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlNodeSet).

[`xmlGetNodePath`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlGetNodePath) returns following values for the nodes of your sample xml matching the `//name` xpath expression:

```
/categories/category[1]/name
/categories/category[2]/name
```

So a specific answer to your question would be: apply xpath expression `("%s/name", xmlGetNodePath(categoryNode))` and process returned array of nodes. For each entry get the text with `xmlNodeListGetString(doc, node->xmlChildrenNode, 1)`.